# Number of solutions to a diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Given a positive integer $n$, consider the diophantine equation $4x^2+y^2+4x+y=2n$ with solutions in non-negative integers $x$ and $y$.

Define the proportion
$$\delta_n=\frac{\#\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2_{\geq0}: 4x^2+y^2+4x+y=2n\}}n.$$

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\delta_n=0.$$

Comment: Yes, it's less than the proportion of integers of the form $8n+5$ which are sum of two squares, which tends to $0$ like $n/\sqrt{\log(n)}$.

Comment: @HenriCohen: if you could add details and references, that could be instructional and useful. I may encourage you to write it as an answer.

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan rearranging the terms we get $(4x+2)^2+(2y+1)^2=8n+5$ or $a^2+b^2=8n+5$.

Comment: Your question is answered here (when you combine with Alapan Das's observation): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264069/number-of-representable-as-sum-of-2-squares